# D3 graph questions about zoom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, graph, icicles

I'm setting a Icicle graph on a old angularjs application. I decided to try d3  graphs and doing some tests...
So basically two questions, for two different codes:

Question 1:
Initially i used this example: https://bl.ocks.org/lorenzopub/c4a226f9c29a20dd0cc152e212a70c9a

I realized that when you zoom in certain areas of the graph, it returns " attribute width: A negative value is not valid. ("-2428.9156626506024")" and even if it makes the zoom it doesnt show the text. 
Any idea why this happens?

Question 2:
Later i tried to make my own structure, using the same json as the previous example. The main difference was that i created a "g" and inside it i placed the "rec" and the "foreignObject", to make it more organized in terms of structure. Code below

I placed the below code in an angularjs directive.

I'm using V4 of d3 "//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"

```
      var totalSize = 0;
      var width = 960, height = 500;
      var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
      var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, height]);
      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);
      var partition = d3.partition()
        .size([width, height])
        .padding(0)
        .round(true);
      var svg = d3.select("#pleaseWork") //.append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
      var groups = svg.selectAll("g");

      d3.json("graphs/dataD3.json", function (error, root) {
        //d3.json("graphs/newData.json", function (error, root) {
        if (error) throw error;
        root = d3.hierarchy(d3.entries(root)[0], function (d) {
            return d3.entries(d.value)
          })
          .sum(function (d) {
            return d.value
          })
          .sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.value - a.value;
          });

        partition(root);
        groups = groups
          .data(root.descendants())
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.key);
          })
          .on("click", clicked);
        //get total size from rect
        totalSize = groups.node().__data__.value;
        console.log(groups.node().__data__.value);
        groups.append('rect')
          .attr("x", function (d) {
            return d.x0;
          })
          .attr("y", function (d) {
            return d.y0;
          })
          .attr("width", function (d) {
            return d.x1 - d.x0;
          })
          .attr("height", function (d) {
            return d.y1 - d.y0;
          });

        groups.append('foreignObject')
          .text(function (d) {
            //return d.data.key + '-' + d.value;
            return d.data.key + ' - ' + (100 * d.value / totalSize).toPrecision(3) + '%';
          })
          .attr("x", function (d) {
            return d.x0;
          })
          .attr("y", function (d) {
            return d.y0;
          })
          .attr("width", function (d) {
            return d.x1 - d.x0;
          })
          .attr("height", function (d) {
            return d.y1 - d.y0;
          });

      });

      function clicked(d) {
        console.log(d);
        x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
        y.domain([d.y0, height]).range([d.depth ? 20 : 0, height]);
        groups.transition()
          .duration(750)
          .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.x0);
          })
          .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.y0);
          })
          .attr("width", function (d) {
            return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0);
          })
          .attr("height", function (d) {
            return y(d.y1) - y(d.y0);
          });
      }
    }
```

When i click on a item to zoom, it enter in the function "clicked" but nothing happens, i wanted to achieve something similar as the first example, where it zooms to that element level.
Thanks in advance for the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the first question with replacing the code from the fo.transition() to:

```
.attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.x0;
      })
      .attr("y", function (d) {
        return d.y0;
      })
      .attr("width", function (d) {
        return d.x1 - d.x0;
      })
      .attr("height", function (d) {
        return d.y1 - d.y0;
      })
```

The second question, i solved like this:

```
      var width = 500,
        height = 300;
      var partitionLayout = d3.partition().size([width, height]);

      //needed for zoom ? 
      var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
      var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, height]);

      //needed to fill the colour
      var colour = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

      d3.json("graphs/newstructure.json", function (data) {
        var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data);
        rootNode.sum(function (d) {
          return d.value;
        });

        // structure the data for the graph
        partitionLayout(rootNode);

        var group = d3.select('#new')
          .selectAll('g')
          .data(rootNode.descendants())
          .enter()
          .append('g')
          .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return colour(d.data.colour);
          })
          .on("click", clicked);

        group.append('rect')
          .attr('x', function (d) {
            console.log(d);
            return d.x0;
          })
          .attr('y', function (d) {
            return d.y0;
          })
          .attr('width', function (d) {
            return d.x1 - d.x0;
          })
          .attr('height', function (d) {
            return d.y1 - d.y0;
          })
          .attr('fill', function (d) {
            return d.data.colour;
          });

        group
          .append('foreignObject')
          .text(function (d) {
            console.log(d);
            return d.data.name + ' - ' + d.value;
          })
          .attr("x", function (d) {
            return d.x0;
          })
          .attr("y", function (d) {
            return d.y0;
          })
          .attr("width", function (d) {
            return d.x1 - d.x0;
          })
          .attr("height", function (d) {
            return d.y1 - d.y0;
          });

        function clicked(d) {
          x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
          y.domain([d.y0, height]).range([d.depth ? 20 : 0, height]);

          group.transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("x", function (d) {
              return x(d.x0);
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
              return y(d.y0);
            })
            .attr("width", function (d) {
              return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0);
            })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
              return y(d.y1) - y(d.y0);
            });

          var rects = d3.select('#new')
            .selectAll('g rect');

          rects.transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("x", function (d) {
              return x(d.x0);
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
              return y(d.y0);
            })
            .attr("width", function (d) {
              return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0);
            })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
              return y(d.y1) - y(d.y0);
            });

          var rects = d3.select('#new')
            .selectAll('g foreignObject');

          rects.transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("x", function (d) {
              return x(d.x0);
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
              return y(d.y0);
            })
            .attr("width", function (d) {
              return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0);
            })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
              return y(d.y1) - y(d.y0);
            });
        }
    });
```